# How to understand this shell script?

Tags: linux

`cat urls.txt | xargs -P 10 -n 1 wget -nH -nc -x]`

This shell is very confusing to new user, just want to ask if there is any reference document I can refer？

Comment: Use [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat+urls.txt+%7C+xargs+-P+10+-n+1+wget+-nH+-nc+-x%5D)!

Comment: What is confusing?  This runs the command `cat` with one argument (the string `urls.txt`).  The output of `cat` is written into a pipe which is read by `xargs`.  Possibly confusing is the fact that the last argument to `xargs` is the odd-looking string `-x]`, and quite possibly that is a typo.  Don't get bogged down in details.  This is just a simple pipeline.

Comment: Most system have manual "man" pages. You can typically type, at the command prompt, man _____, and it will then show you a terse page about the program/command. man cat; man xargs, man wget, etc.

Comment: And after being completely confused by the terse language of the `man` page entries, just try searching the interweb by topic for tutorials or search here for other Qs already mentioning these terms. AND better to read the [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) because requests for tutorials are off topic here. You might do better on https://superuser.com, but I think that site may have simliar restrictions to scope of Q. `xargs` and ` wget` are both very flexible and hence complex commands, so try to find simple Qs first to understand the basics. GOod luck.

Comment: @ William Pursell was right  should be : cat urls.txt | xargs -P 10 -n 1 wget -nH -nc -x but running with error : xargs: wget: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much confusing about it.
If you want to know what the commands do then use the manual.

```
man cat
man xargs
```

The pipe sends the output of one command to the next, in this case `cat urls.txt` to `xargs`.
`cat urls.txt` will write the contents of the file `urls.txt` to stdout, which is then used as the input for `xargs`.
`xargs -P 10 -n 1` will execute a command with with the input (the contents of urls.txt) as arguments. The command in this case being `wget -nH -nc -x]`. I don't know what ] is supposed to do there, but that's probably a typo.

All in all you can understand, without much caring about the options, that this will download a list of files that is in urls.txt into your current directory. Of course it's always safe to check the options flags. in this case `-nc` for example causees wget to rename a downloaded file and append a number if the file is already in the directory.

All three man pages can also be found online:

- [cat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)
- [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)
- [wget](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this book https://www.iiitd.edu.in/~amarjeet/Files/SM2012/Linux%20Dummies%209th.pdf

**And best way to learn Linux command** is use man command

example : 
type > man xargs on terminal you will get all detail

[image]

you will get **man page** for all linux comman

The best way is follow this link https://explainshell.com